# Change Bootstrap Alert Class using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have alert in my html form like below

```
 <div class="alert bg-danger text-white alert-dismissible" id="alert" >
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>&times;</span></button>
    <span class="font-weight-semibold"><a href="#" class="alert-link" id="message">Please check your credentials</a>.
</div>
```

When user submit form, I am checking form input and based on result I am changing alert text like below using jquery.

```
$("#error").show();
$('#error').html('Invalid EmailId or Password !');
```

Its working fine, however I want alert class success on successfully login, I am not getting idea how I can change the class from

```
alert bg-danger text-white alert-dismissible
```

to

```
alert bg-success text-white alert-dismissible
```

I am trying like this but its not working

```
$("#alert").attr("alert bg-danger text-white alert-dismissible", "alert bg-success text-white alert-dismissible");
```

Let me know if anyone here can help me for solve the puzzle for me.

Thanks!

Comment: You actually want to change the class only. You can try ```$("#alert").removeClass("bg-danger").addClass("bg-success");```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [elem.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) . no need to replace entire class just toggle between `danger and success`

```
$("#alert").toggleClass("bg-danger bg-success");
```